# jQuery is hiding all <li> tags

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, filtering

Running into some issues with jQuery as I am fairly new with it, I have some jQuery code thats hiding a filter menu of `<li>` items. However, when I use this it also hides the `<li>` tags I am using in the main menu header.

I was thinking of assigning a specific class name for `<li>` to be hidden, but they are already using specific names. (e.g., accounting, courier etc.)

How can I hide only the specific `<li>` tags and not the ones in the main menu header?
Can I assign a different identifier to the `<li>`s I want to hide?

**HTML code for li to be hidden:**

```
<div class="tags">
<div id="col">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="accounting" />Accounting</label>
</div>
<div id="col">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="courier" />Courier</label>
</div>
<div id="col">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="project-management" />Project Management</label>
</div>
<div id="col">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />Video Games</label>
</div>
</div>

<ul class="results">
<li class="accounting" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="http://cnn.com" style="text-decoration: none">Accounting</a>

</li>
<li class="courier" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="{{ path('job1') }}" style="text-decoration: none">Courier / Parcel Delivery</a>

</li>
<li class="project-management" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="{{ path('job3') }}" style="text-decoration: none">Game QA Project Management</a>

</li>
<li class="video-games" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="http://cnn.com" style="text-decoration: none">Video Games</a>

</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery code** (is hiding all li tags)

```
<script>
    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
        var vals = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get();
        $('li').hide().filter(function () {
            return ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'), vals) > -1)
        }).show()
        if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) $('li').show()
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try improving the selector to be more specific, like so:

```
<script>
    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
        var vals = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get();
        $('.results li').hide().filter(function () {
            return ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'), vals) > -1)
        }).show()
        if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) $('.results li').show()
    });
</script>
```

The change from `$('li')` to `$('.results li')` will cause it to only select list elements within the `ul` with the `results` class.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to replace the `jquery` selector `li` by your `container-class li` like so

```
.results li
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v3ynnwx3/)